# What duration of a white noise burst is required for it to be "white" at a given frequency or frequency range?

Tags: frequency, resonance, noise

I am running white noise bursts (with very short ramps on/off to prevent discontinuities) through underdamped resonant bandpasses which are tuned to any given $f_0$ and an underdamped $Q$.

Continuous white noise at an amplitude of $1$ if run through a completely underdamped resonant bandpass should bring that resonant bandpass to $1$ at its $f_0$.

But what about short bursts? And what about where a little damping is involved?

### Purpose

I would like to excite the bandpasses to the amplitude of the noise signal at their $f_0$ (say amplitude of $1$) with the shortest duration of noise possible in any given case.

For reference, I am not interested in Kronecker's delta as it does not perform what I need to - I need the smooth signal of white noise for this purpose.

### 1) Minimum duration of white noise for a given freq

I suspect that in all circumstances, a burst of white noise must have a duration of at least the period of the $f_0$ of the desired frequency to excite. If it is shorter than the period, and it does not have discontinuities (no steps) due to soft ramp on/off, then how can it adequately have the low frequency information needed?

When I test too short bursts (<1 period of $f_0$) they don't seem to activate the lower frequencies as much as longer bursts.

Due to random variation in the noise, I suspect even 2-3 periods may be needed to be reasonably sure you have reached amplitude of $1$ at $f_0$ but I am not sure.

Is this correct? Ie. What duration of white noise might typically be required for it to be reliably or at least reasonably "white" (full amplitude achieved) at a given frequency?

I originally thought I could reliably feed say 1-3 periods of white noise through each filter (duration tuned to $n/f_0$ for the bandpass) and get a reliable response across the spectrum. But this isn't happening. This seems reasonable on the low frequencies, but the high frequencies are not adequately excited. Unless I made an error.

So I am not sure how to standardize the duration to the minimum needed or what is happening.

What duration of white noise is needed to be "white" at a given frequency or across a frequency range?

### 2) The effects of damping

In any underdamped case, would the $Q$ of a bandpass be expected to affect the duration of a white noise burst required to excite it fully?

I suspect not, since a narrow bandwidth resonant bandpass still allows the signal through at full amplitude (in theory) at $f_0$. So I suspect the only problem I have is not knowing what the shortest duration of noise I can get away with is for each frequency target.

Thanks for any help. Hopefully that at least makes sense.

Comment: I don’t think the notion of “whiteness” *at a given frequency* makes sense. White noise *must* have a range of frequencies. I also think this question is more about the human auditory system than about physics.

Comment: No, not about the auditory system. 5 samples of a white noise signal are not "white" at a given sample rate and all frequencies. All white noise has limitations. It is just a signal. If you truncate it too short it will no longer represent all frequencies. Factually this must be true. White noise is only white after a certain duration of it exists. Any tiny fragment of a white noise segment cannot necessarily be white. Or would you suggest a 2 sample segment could be white? A 3-5 sample segment? What 3 samples could make a white signal except a Kronecker? It is not possible. There is a limit.